# Changing the name of the list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents

In fact, I want to change the name of the listoffigures but I wasn't able to do it even if I have used the appropriate command

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Liste des figures}



\begin{document}




\listoffigures

\listoftables

\clearpage


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
\def\frenchlistfigurename{Liste des figures}
```

[image]

Also, the option name `francais` is deprecated. Use `[french]` instead, and load it with the document class.